# match incoming string with lookup strings

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to achieve one requirement.

I'm recieving files and each file is contaning some secret info within first 50 characters.

For example its my input file string

```
String input = "Check      this     answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
```

Then I have one lookup file given below

lookup strings

```
this answer|Do this
not answer|Do that
example yes|Dont do
```

I want to match my secret info which could be present in first 50 characters with lookup strings.
Like in my example "this answer"  in lookup strings getting match with "this     answer" but spaces are there.

So value is there but with extra spaces. That's not a problem. Info is there that's important. So that's a match

After match in info am going to use action info from lookup string. Like in this example would be "Do this"

How can I make this kind of matches using java or regex?

I've tried with contains functions of java but not getting am looking for.

Thanks in Advance  for all suggestions

Comment: Your question mentions Java, but you've tagged it with JavaScript. I'm guessing based on `string` that this should be a Java question instead, so I've retagged it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces from your string or add `"\s*"` between words in your look-up strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
String input = "Check      this     answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<String, String>();
lookup.put(".*this\\s+answer.+", "Do this");
lookup.put(".*not\\s+answer.+", "Do that");
lookup.put(".*example\\s+yes.+", "Dont do");

for (String regexKey : lookup.keySet()) {
    if (input.matches(regexKey)) {
        System.out.println(lookup.get(regexKey));
    }
}
```

Or to make sure the match is in the first 50 chars:

```
String input = "Check      this     answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<String, String>();
// Match with ^ from beginning of string and by placing parentheses we can measure the matched string when match is found.
lookup.put("(^.*this\\s+answer).*", "Do this");
lookup.put("(^.*not\\s+answer).*", "Do that");
lookup.put("(^.*example\\s+yes).*", "Dont do");


for (String regexKey : lookup.keySet()) {
    Matcher matchRegexKey = Pattern.compile(regexKey).matcher(input);
    if (matchRegexKey.matches()) {
        // Check match is in first 50 chars.
        if (matchRegexKey.group(1).length() <= 50) {
            System.out.println(lookup.get(regexKey));
        }
    }
}
```